# Run Sub-procedure with Procedure name as a string

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm wanting to run a procedure from a form that was open via openargs

This is how I am opening the form.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Loading_Form", acNormal, , , , acWindowNormal, DynaProgBarMax & "|" & DynaLableCaption & "|" & ProcCall & "|"
```

This is what is ran when the form opens.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim OpenArgsAry As Variant

OpenArgsAry = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
Me.DynaProgBar.Max = OpenArgsAry(0)
Me.DynaLable.Caption = OpenArgsAry(1)
Run OpenArgsAry(2)

End Sub
```

I am having an issue with `Run OpenArgsAry(2)`. I'm getting an error stating that the Procedure can not be found. `OpenArgsAry(2)` is containing a string `"Forms(""Stuff"").PrintAllStuff()"`. When I Replace `Run OpenArgsAry(2)` with `Run Forms("Stuff").PrintAllStuff()` it works fine.

`Run` is suppose to be able to run a string as the procedure name is it not?

Comment: Run Forms("Stuff").PrintAllStuff(), this you have mentioned, it is different from Run Forms(""Stuff"").PrintAllStuff(), which the code is giving. Difference is in double quotations used with Stuff.

Comment: @mmehta Double quotes are required for quotes within a string. That string is still displayed as `Forms("Stuff").PrintAllStuff()`

Comment: Try putting bracket when you use Run. so in your case Run (OpenArgsAry(2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Run` requires a procedure (sub or function in a global module, not a form or class module). `PrintAllStuff` is a method on a form, thus can't be executed through `Run`.

However, you can execute it through `CallByName`:

```
CallByName Forms("Stuff"), OpenArgsAry(2), vbMethod
```

Where `OpenArgsAry(2)` only contains `PrintAllStuff`. You can use `Me` instead if you want to execute the method on the current form.

Comment: Okay this might work. How would can I pass the object (that being `Forms("Stuff")`) as a variable? Reason being is this would keep me from having to make multiple forms that serve the same purpose.

Comment: As said, you can use `Me` if it's the current form. You can use an extra OpenArg if you want the form  name to be variable: `CallByName Forms(OpenArgsAry(2)), OpenArgsAry(3), vbMethod`

Comment: This works. I ran into another problem that I need to figure out. Thanks for the help!